# Extract struct array with smallest value of one variable

Tags: c++

So let's say I have the following struct

```
struct BadQuestion
{
   float a;
   float b;

} BadArray[10];
```

Now I need to check which array[i] has the *second* smallest value of 'float a'. Because I later need to extract 'float b' from the array with the smallest 'float a'.

I have looked at examples like [this](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-and-minimum-in-an-array/) but it seems a bit excessive. Is there a simpler and quick way to do achieve this?

**Update 1:**

```
bool cmp(const BadQuestion& lhs, const BadQuestion& rhs)
{
    return lhs.a < rhs.a;
}

auto mini = std::min_element(BadArray, BadArray + 10, cmp);
mini->a
```

This would give me the minimum value, which is a neat step. But I need the `second` lowest value.

Comment: [`std::nth_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element) would be a decent candidate if order retention is not required. Outstanding `struct` name, btw.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks. I've updated the question. Do you think it's achievable using min_element the way I did it?

Comment: That will find you're smallest element in the sequence. To find the *second* smallest will require a relocation of the smallest, then a repeat of `min_element`. 2*O(N) is probably ok, but don't use it as a general solution for the `nth` smallest, which can in worst case devolve to N*N/2, i.e. O(N^2). Better algorithms exist for the general case, but for yours, a doubled up min_element will probably work fine. Btw, that second parameter should be `BadArray + n`, where `n` is the number of elements. A task-specific forward-single-scan would likely also work for your specific need.

Comment: I'd also call it `__flBadIdentifier` (consecutive underscores are reserved and cannot be used in identifiers in any place)

Comment: Where'd the whole "let's prefix all my variables with double underscores" come from, anyway?

Comment: @AtlasC1 Maybe bad habit, but usually double underscore are global variables while single underscore are local. It just makes it easier for me to keep track.

Comment: @Zute Any name containing a double underscore, or starting with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter, is a reserved word. You shouldn't use them in your code.

Answer (score 0):

The straightforward method is simple:

```
// n is assumed to be at least 2
int i0 = array[0].a<array[1].a ? 0 : 1, i1 = 1 - i0;
for (int i=2; i<n; i++) {
    if (array[i].a < array[i1].a) {
        if (array[i].a < array[i0].a) {
            i1 = i0; i0 = i;
        } else {
            i1 = i;
        }
    }
}
// i0 is index of smallest a value, i1 is index of second-smallest
```

and I'm quite sure that modern compilers will translate this into reasonably optimized machine code (however may be using `floats` is not a good idea for speed).

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions, depending on whether you care about order.

If you do *not* care about the ordering of any of the elements after this operation, you can use the standard algorithm [nth_element](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element). It will reorder your elements though:

```
template <typename Iter, typename Cmp>
typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type
nth_smallest_reorder(Iter begin, Iter end, int n, Cmp cmp) {
    std::nth_element(begin, begin + n, end, cmp);
    return *(begin + n);
}
```

If you *do* care about the ordering, then you can do one of two things. First, you can just straight up copy the entire array:

```
template <typename Iter, typename Cmp>
typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type
nth_smallest_copy(Iter begin, Iter end, int n, Cmp cmp) {
    std::vector<typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type> cpy(begin, end);
    std::nth_element(cpy.begin(), cpy.begin() + n, cpy.end(), cmp);
    return cpy[n];
}
```

Or, you can keep a running sorted list of size at most`n+1`:

```
template <typename Iter, typename Cmp>
typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type
nth_smallest_no_copy(Iter begin, Iter end, int n, Cmp cmp) {
    std::vector<typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type> n_best;
    n_best.reserve(n + 2);

    for (; begin != end; ++begin) {
        if (n_best.empty() || cmp(*begin, n_best.back())) {
            n_best.insert(
                std::lower_bound(n_best.begin(), n_best.end(), *begin, cmp),
                *begin);

            if (n_best.size() > n + 1) n_best.resize(n + 1);
         }
    }

    return n_best.back();
}
```